# How to debug and get error messages while writing javascript/p5.js code with Flask backend on Sublime text?

Tags: javascript, debugging, error-handling, p5.js

My current web app project is based on Flask backend in a virtual machine. I use Sublime Text to write the code, the command line to run `Flask run`, and I view the pages on `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` in a web browser. I see error messages when there is problem with the Flask backend.

My folder structure is as follows:

```
app.py
/templates
    index.html
/static
    /css
    /js
        my_js.js
```

I am new to Flask and JavaScript, and I am not sure how I can see error messages to debug the `my_js.js` code.

Comment: Are you familiar with [the JavaScript console](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/javascript/developer-tools)?

Comment: I am brand new to web dev. I saw that before but didn't realize it's used to debug js. Now I know, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I mentioned in my comment, it sounds like you're looking for your browser's [developer tools](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/javascript/developer-tools), specifically the JavaScript console.

At the very least, you should be checking the JavaScript console for errors. You can also use `console.log()` calls to get more information, or use the JavaScript debugger. It's not uncommon for a web developer to keep their JavaScript console open in a separate window most of the time.

In addition to that, your developer tools have other features, including the ability to inspect HTML content and network traffic. And you don't have to install anything extra: it all comes with every modern browser.

For more information, I'd recommend googling "chrome developer tools" or "firefox developer tools" depending on your browser. Here are a few resources to get you started:

- [What are browser developer tools? - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools)
- [Chrome DevTools - Google](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/)
- [JavaScript Debugging - W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp)

It might also be possible to debug JavaScript directly from Sublime Text. I'm not an expert there, so I honestly don't know. But I'd start with your browser's developer tools anyway. Good luck!